# Node / Javascript : How to write out an array of key values pairs to a csv file, with the keys as the header?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, csv, key-value

Using Node.js, how would I write out a csv file from an array containing key value pairs?

here is an example array of key/value pairs I want to write out.

```
function testWriteCsv() {
    const arr = []
    const kp1 = []
    const kp2 = []
    const kp3 = []

    kp1['FIRST_NAME'] = 'First Name1';
    kp1['LAST_NAME'] = 'First Name1';

    kp2['FIRST_NAME'] = 'First Name2';
    kp2['LAST_NAME'] = 'First Name2';

    kp3['FIRST_NAME'] = 'First Name3';
    kp3['LAST_NAME'] = 'First Name3';

    arr.push(kp1)
    arr.push(kp2)
    arr.push(kp3)

    console.log('arr', arr)

    // now I want to write out a .csv file of the above data, with header:
    // FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME
}
```

I have tried using the following libraries, following the examples, but none of them work for an array of key value pairs.

None of the following libraries have a function that I can pass an array of key/value pairs, and have it assist writing out a .csv.

I have attempted contorting the array, interating through, doing various things, using the following libraries, and none of them work.

```
fs
fast-csv
convert-array-to-csv
csv-writer
```

I would ask, that if you have done this before, and have a fully working example, please share, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

---

**Update:**

This is a full working example from one solution:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function testWriteCsv() {
    const arr = [];
    const kp1 = [];
    const kp2 = [];
    const kp3 = [];

    kp1['FIRST_NAME'] = 'First Name1';
    kp1['LAST_NAME'] = 'First Name1';

    kp2['FIRST_NAME'] = 'First Name2';
    kp2['LAST_NAME'] = 'First Name2';

    kp3['FIRST_NAME'] = 'First Name3';
    kp3['LAST_NAME'] = 'First Name3';

    arr.push(kp1);
    arr.push(kp2);
    arr.push(kp3);

    // 'output' will hold the full csv result to be written to file
    const headers = Object.keys(arr[0]);
    let output = headers.join() + '\n';

    for (let kv of arr) {
        let values = Object.values(kv).join() + '\n';
        output += values
    }

    // Write to a file
    fs.writeFile("test.csv", output, function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    });
}

testWriteCsv()
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably can be done better with one of the libraries you mentioned, but I'm guessing your problem was descontructing the array into a string that can be saved into a file so I'm leaving a plain example:

```
// Required for writing into file (writeFile())
const fs = require('fs');

// Constructing the array (same as original)
const arr = [];
const kp1 = [];
const kp2 = [];
const kp3 = [];

kp1['FIRST_NAME'] = 'First Name1';
kp1['LAST_NAME'] = 'Last Name1';

kp2['FIRST_NAME'] = 'First Name2';
kp2['LAST_NAME'] = 'Last Name2';

kp3['FIRST_NAME'] = 'First Name3';
kp3['LAST_NAME'] = 'Last Name3';

arr.push(kp1);
arr.push(kp2);
arr.push(kp3);

// Output will hold the whole text, starting with the Header
output = Object.keys(arr[0]).join(',') + '\n';

// Add line by line to the output
for(kp of arr) {
    output += Object.values(kp).join(',') + '\n';
}

// Write to a file
fs.writeFile("test.csv", output, function(err) {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

This will generate the following **output** variable (and save it into a file):

```
FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME
First Name1,Last Name1
First Name2,Last Name2
First Name3,Last Name3
```

If this works for you, you can then split the logic into separated functions or use a library where you see fit.

**// EDIT**

Old way of generating output, for reference:

```
// Get headers from the keys from the first child of the array (arr[0] would be kp1)
let [col1, col2] = Object.keys(arr[0]);

// Output will hold the whole text, starting with the Header
output = col1 + ',' + col2 + '\n';

// Add line by line to the output
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    output += arr[i][col1] + ',' + arr[i][col2] + '\n';
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I will give this a try.  Is there a way though, with any library to have the headers generated from the keys in the key/value pair?  (instead of specifying in the variable output)?

Comment: Hi, sadly I don't use javascript so I have no idea of a library, however you could get them from the array itself using the keys() method, but aren't you the one defining the key? If that's not the case I could add how to get it from the array but @Ayyub's answer seems like a much better alternative.

Comment: I modified the answer to get the keys from the array with the **key()** method as you mentioned. Good luck.

Comment: Awesome, this works.

I am not defining the key.  It is defined as a column name in a database, created by someone else (determining column names).

And so I query the DB, read into a key/value pair, each row added to an array, then I do some work with the data, and want to write out some fields to a .csv.

For me to code the headers in, from the database header values would be problematic, as the db column names may change.

I will give the modified code a try, thank you very much.

Comment: Oh I see, but if you're getting the headers from the db and then creating the array yourself, at some point you're holding the name of the columns on a variable, you could use those unless I'm understanding wrong, but anyway, the code above should still work. I would still consider the possibility of creating the variable with a json structure instead of an array and then using Yash's suggestion, you could create a separate question on how to form the json and show some of the code from when you get the data. Anyway, your choice of course and glad I could help!

Comment: Thank you, I could not get the examples below to work, but this worked.  I just need to find out how to not code in the key values anywhere in the script, and I'm good to go.

Comment: Replacing the variable 'output', and for loop with this works:

output = headers.join() + '\n';

for (let kv of arr) {
    let values = Object.values(kv).join() + '\n';
    output += values
}

Comment: That's even better than the last edit I did, you're just missing a comma inside the join function. I'll edit my answer with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for passing a key-value pair and converting that into a CSV.

Library needed `npm install jsonexport`

For the Code :

```
    var jsonexport = require('jsonexport');

    const arr = []
    const kp1 = {}
    const kp2 = {}
    const kp3 = {}

    kp1['FIRST_NAME'] = 'First Name1';
    kp1['LAST_NAME'] = 'First Name1';

    kp2['FIRST_NAME'] = 'First Name2';
    kp2['LAST_NAME'] = 'First Name2';

    kp3['FIRST_NAME'] = 'First Name3';
    kp3['LAST_NAME'] = 'First Name3';

    arr.push(kp1)
    arr.push(kp2)
    arr.push(kp3)

    console.log('arr', arr)

    jsonexport(arr,function(err, csv){
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(csv);
});
```

Output :

```
FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME
First Name1,First Name1
First Name2,First Name2
First Name3,First Name3
```

> Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Excellent, let me give this a try.

Comment: Follow up.  thank you, but this did not work.

If you copy/paste the array of key/value pairs, and pass to the function:  ```jsonexport(arr, ..., it prints nothing and fails.```

In the example you gave, contacts is not an array of key value pairs as given in the example ```(arr)```.

Comment: Just give me a few minutes i’ll work it out. If you just convert kP1 kp2 kp3 to have ‘kP1 = {}’ And so on for the remaining 2, it will work correctly. Will share the code.

Comment: @user10664542 I have updated the code please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

`csv-writer` library was made for this type of use-case in mind. With your example code, you can use `csv-writer` like this:

```js
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter

function testWriteCsv() {
  const arr = []
  const kp1 = []
  const kp2 = []
  const kp3 = []

  kp1['FIRST_NAME'] = 'First Name1';
  kp1['LAST_NAME'] = 'First Name1';

  kp2['FIRST_NAME'] = 'First Name2';
  kp2['LAST_NAME'] = 'First Name2';

  kp3['FIRST_NAME'] = 'First Name3';
  kp3['LAST_NAME'] = 'First Name3';

  arr.push(kp1)
  arr.push(kp2)
  arr.push(kp3)

  console.log('arr', arr)

  // now I want to write out a .csv file of the above data, with header:
  // FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME
  const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
    path: 'file.csv',
    header: [
      {id: 'FIRST_NAME', title: 'FIRST_NAME'},
      {id: 'LAST_NAME', title: 'LAST_NAME'}
    ]
  })
  return csvWriter.writeRecords(arr)
}

testWriteCsv().then(() => console.log('Finished'))
```

Output `file.csv` should have the following contents.

```
FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME
First Name1,First Name1
First Name2,First Name2
First Name3,First Name3
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) node module. It is available via cdn also.
By array of key/value pairs you mean Array of objects or array of arrays, i am giving example for both.

First map through your array of objects. Create a table string and give that table string to xlsx module. It can convert string to xlsx or csv

You can put any column heading via wrapping it within

For example:

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx')
let arr = [
{
    firstname: 'First Name1',
    lastname: 'last Name1'
},{
    firstname: 'First Name2',
    lastname: 'last Name2'
},{
    firstname: 'First Name3',
    lastname: 'last Name3'
},{
    firstname: 'First Name4',
    lastname: 'last Name4'
}
]
// if you have array of objects
let tablerows = arr.map((arr, index) => {
return "<tr><td>" + arr.firstname + '</td><td>' + arr.lastname + '</td></tr>'
}

//if you have array of array as you described in question
let tablerows = arr.map((arr, index) => {
return "<tr><td>" + arr.FIRST_NAME + '</td><td>' + arr.LAST_NAME + '</td></tr>'
}

let table = '<table>\
         <thead>\
         <tr>\
            <th>First Name</th>\
            <th>Last Name</th>\
        </tr>\
        </thead>' + tablerows.join('') + '</table>'

let workbook = xlsx.read(table, { type: 'string' });
xlsx.writeFile(workbook, "filename.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you, but this did not work.

The arr you provided in the example is not an array of key/value pairs.

Also I'm not sure what <table> is, the <tr> <td> <th>, have never seen that, and I do not understand the syntax of
 that code, and I can not find it in any node.js documentation anywhere after searching the docs.

This is valuable however, making me aware of the xlsx library, which I will look into, as I have some upcoming .xlsx
 processing to do.